# Is it possible to drag & drop between custom VS Code tree views?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The 1.66 (March 2022) release introduces a [TreeDragAndDropController](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeDragAndDropController%3CT%3E) API which allows for handling drag & drop events for custom tree views.

However in the docs for the [DataTransfer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/dc2f5d8dd1790ac4fc6054e11b44e36884caa4be/src/vscode-dts/vscode.d.ts#L9783-L9786) object is says:

> Drag and drop controllers that implement {@link TreeDragAndDropController.handleDrag `handleDrag`} can add additional mime types to the data transfer. These additional mime types will only be included in the `handleDrop` when the the drag was initiated from an element in the same drag and drop controller.

Does this mean that you cannot drag & drop between custom tree views as they would typically have a custom drag & drop controller per view? Or that you're meant to re-use a drag & drop controller between tree views in order to enable dragging & dropping between views?

I have tried various combinations and been unsuccessful in getting a full drag & drop between two tree views. I do see an error in the console on drop in some situations but that is about it.

Comment: That is a confusing passage.  I "assume" it means that you can only use the `treeDataTransfer.set('application/vnd.code.tree.<your tree id>',  mimetype - you cannot use any others.  Have you tested using only that - you probably have>.  So in the drop only use `sources.get('application/vnd.code.tree.<our tree id>')` to get the dropped value.  But I can't test that.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure out how to get drag & drop to work between two different treeviews. For me, the problem was a combination of:

- Misunderstanding the purpose / usage of `dragMimeTypes`.
- Misunderstanding the purpose / usage of `treeDataTransfer.set()`.
- Using an incorrect naming convention for mime types.

This is probably best described by way of example.
Let's assume we're only going to drag from **TreeView_A** and we'll only drop onto **TreeView_B**.

For **TreeView_A**

- `dropMimeTypes` can be an empty array as we're not expecting to receive any drops.
- We don't really need a handleDrop() method, again we're not expecting to receive any drops.
- `dragMimeTypes` needs to include the mime type of the treeview that we're going to drop onto (i.e. **TreeView_B**). A word of warning here, this **MUST** be in the format `application/vnd.code.tree.<treeidlowercase>`. So, for this example it would read something like this:

```
dragMimeTypes = ['application/vnd.code.tree.treeView_b'];
```

- `handleDrag()` method needs to set using a mime type of the target treeview (**Treeview_B**), (remember lowercase!)

```
    public async handleDrag(source: TreeItem[], treeDataTransfer: vscode.DataTransfer, token: vscode.CancellationToken): Promise<void> {
        treeDataTransfer.set('application/vnd.code.tree.treeView_b', new vscode.DataTransferItem(source));
    }
```

The lowercase requirement seems more like a suggestion if you read the comments in the underlying code... but no from my experience it seems more like a requirement. Had me stumped for ages!

For **TreeView_B**

- `dragMimeTypes` can be an empty array as we won't be dragging anything from here.
- similarly, we don't really need a `handleDrag()` method.
- `dropMimeTypes` needs to include the mime type of the treeview that we're going to drop onto (i.e. this treeview, **TreeView_B**)

```
dropMimeTypes = ['application/vnd.code.tree.treeView_b'];
```

- the `handleDrop()` method needs to get the correct mime type (you guessed it, **Treeview_B** in lowercase). In this method, I just log to console.

```
    public async handleDrop(target: TreeItem | undefined, sources: vscode.DataTransfer): Promise<void> {
        const transferItemAppContent = sources.get('application/vnd.code.tree.treeView_b');
        if (transferItemAppContent) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(transferItemAppContent));
            return;
        }
    }
```

I'm still not sure that I've 100% understood how this is supposed to be implemented, but I can tell you that the above method works. Hope it helps.